# Layering or overriding ActiveProfiles within the Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing

Is there a way to override an `@ActiveProfile` set by a test superclass within Spring?

Here's my configuration:

```xml
<beans profile="integration">
    <bean class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.mycompany.MyInterface" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="production,one-off-test">
    <bean class="com.mycompany.MyInterfaceImpl" />
</beans>
```

The superclass to all the tests looks like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
public abstract class TestBase {
```

And in my new test class I would like to do this:

```
@ActiveProfiles("one-off-test")
public class MyTest extends TestBase {
```

Not inheriting from TestBase isn't really an option.
When I try to run this, the error I get is:

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.MyInterface] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.MyInterface] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.easymock.EasyMock#1,com.mycompany.MyInterfaceImpl#0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:970)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 46 more
```

What would be even better is to be able to layer the profiles, so that if a bean exists for profile `one-off-test` inject that, otherwise inject the `integration` profile bean.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to the problem you presented is to use `primary` like this:

```
<beans profile="integration">
    <bean class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock" primary=true>
        <constructor-arg value="com.mycompany.MyInterface" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

You don't need to change anything else because Spring will use the bean from profile `integration` wherever a bean of type `MyInterface`. Spring does that despite the fact that there are multiple beans of that type present.

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) which gives a few more details on how `primary` works.

Comment: Beautiful and elegant solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

You may need to specify the active profiles through System Properties:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="integration"
```

in case you want to use the related bean implementation or

```
-Dspring.profiles.active="one-off-test"
```

to use the *one-off-test* profile beans.

Then you will have to set the `inheritProfiles` annotation propertyto `false` which will prevent the current annotated test case to discart subclass profiles:

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"one-off-test"}, inheritProfiles= false)
public class MyTest extends TestBase {}
```

Comment: Nice! +1! The existence of `inheritProfiles` had slipped my mind

Comment: Yes, if could even have slipped mine if I dind't came across it when faced a similar situation :D